# ERROR in flutter: widget_test.dart cannot detect MyApp() pls helpme

Tags: flutter

Being a total beginner I am trying out various flutter feature and I am stuck at running the main.dart due to errors in the widget_test.dart file. Please point out if the error is due to some other reason.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_app/pages/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:food_app/pages/StarterPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
  home: StarterPage(),
)
```

);

widget_test.dart

```
// This is a basic Flutter widget test.
//
 // To perform an interaction with a widget in your test, use the WidgetTester
 // utility that Flutter provides. For example, you can send tap and scroll
// gestures. You can also use WidgetTester to find child widgets in the widget
// tree, read text, and verify that the values of widget properties are correct.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:food_app/main.dart';

void main() {
 testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  // Build our app and trigger a frame.
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

 // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
 expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
 expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

// Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
await tester.pump();

// Verify that our counter has incremented.
expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
```

});
}

Answer (score 1):

This `widget_test.dart` file is a file for your tests (obviously). It is separate of your main code and its purpose is only for writing unit, widget, integration and probably some other tests.

I believe that your question came up because your IDE shows you a problem in that code. You don't have to worry about it. As long as you run `flutter run` or `flutter build` tests aren't touched.

[image: Problems in VS Code related to <code>widget_test.dart</code>]

You can delete the whole `tests/` directory if you don't plan on maintaining them.

I deeply suggest you learn about Flutter unit and widget tests as you and your skills will benefit from it, it is also an industry standard to write tests. You can learn more about them in [Testing Flutter apps](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing). If you're only getting started with Flutter, you can leave it for later though.

However, if you plan to fix those test, firstly, you should put your `MaterialApp` in some custom widget, for example `FoodApp` (guessing from the package name) and pump *it* in tests. You will need to tweak those tests a little bit more than that. Please refer to the resource I linked above.